# Custom Properties in Linq Generated Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

It makes more sense to use an integer in the database, but I want to pretend it's always been a string (and not the string corresponding to the int) because it's simpler.

The reason behind this is that the user-facing view is an encrypted version of the string, but I never want to see the int unless working directly with the database (the int is an IDENTITY column).

So, I have a LINQ mapping which I want to replace.  Basically, I wish to replace this (which is in the designer)

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute] //...
public int TID
{
    get
    {
        return this._TID;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._TID != value))
        {
            this.OnTIDChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._TID = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("TID");
            this.OnTIDChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

With this

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute] //...
public string TID
{
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToString(this._TID + 5);
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._TID - 5 != Int32.Parse(value)))
        {
            this.OnTIDChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._TID = Int32.Parse(value) - 5;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("TID");
            this.OnTIDChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow me to, for example, use a `asp:QueryStringParameter` in the `WhereParameters` of a `LinqDataSource` instead of remapping the query string in the code-behind.

Comment: You should be careful with @Chad's answer if you are running a Linq2Sql query against that property because L2S will assume that it's a column in the table and throw back an error when it doesn't find it

Comment: @Jose: That could probably be solved with LinqKIT, but that doesn't help with `LinqDataSource`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of remapping like that try extending the linq class and adding a new Property to the class

```
Public string TIDstring
{
get { return (this.TID + 5).toString(); }
set
    {
       int val = 0;
       if (int.TryParse(value, out val)
           this.TID = val - 5;
       else
           throw new Exception("Invalid TID Value")
    }

}
```

Comment: This is why the linq to sql classes are all partial class, you can extend them in another file without them being overwritten if you regenerate the entity class.

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason my brain decided that only the DataContext itself was a partial class, even though I had the designer code opened right in front of me.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem fully, because my new property "has no supported translation to SQL." So, it helps a lot but does not fix the issue with needing to handle `asp:QueryStringParameter` in the code-behind (e.g., in a `WhereParameters` element).

Comment: I know this isnt what you are wanting but you could stick the value in a hiddenfield on page load and use a control parameter.

Comment: That looks better, but I think it's morally equivalent to what I'm doing now (i.e., figuring out the value in the code-behind).  I suspect this isn't solvable.  I'm trying to run the translation on the query parameter and use that to compare to the database whereas Linq is more designed to run the translation on the database column and compare that to the query parameter.  I don't think it's support both, and suspect the fact that I want to do this hints at me not having a strong intuition about how it LINQ works.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `Where` property of your `SqlDataSource` to do something like this:

```
Where = "it.[TID] = (@TID - 5)"
```

Comment: Idea came to me this weekend posted as seperate answer because it is seperate from the one above.

Comment: As mentioned, what I'm actually doing is encrypting the integer and using a string representation of the result.  I don't think a `LinqDataSource` where clause can handle that.

Comment: Unless you had a decryption function then in your sql server a QueryStringParameter is not going to work for you.

Comment: I stuck the encryption and decryption in my get/set functions, much in the same way you added/subtracted 5 in your other answer's get/set functions.